# Ubuntu 17.10 is broken | Apps wont run

Tags: 17.10

For the 3rd time I find myself trying out Ubuntu 17 and its a new problem every time.

#### This time, some apps that I have downloaded will not open.

- *Typora* (a markdown editor), downloaded from official Typora site, I click on the launcher... nothing happens
- I tried to download *Peek* from the Ubuntu Software center so I could document this bug and get help from Typora devs and bam.... Peek doesn't open so now I can't even show you guys what i'm dealing with.

If anyone can help I would be most grateful. Please beware that I am a fairly new Linux user so if there is some information that I need to fetch please include a how-to.

Comment: not completely sure. it did that after I submitted the post
_i accidentally typed in xenial in the tags_

Comment: As a new user, we generally suggest sticking with software from the Ubuntu repositories (see the answer[s] below). Software in the Ubuntu repositories is tested and supported. Random software from the rest of the internet is not. Effectively diagnosing and debugging Linux software is a complex task requiring skills and experience. This is not the right venue to learn those skills.

Comment: I appreciate your concern, but Typora is tested only on Ubuntu so I know it works. I also got it to work in 16.04 too if that counts for anything so I myself know that it works. So I really would just prefer a fix for it rather than someone telling me to go the "safe" Ubuntu software route. As I mentioned before I tried installing Peek which comes in Ubuntu repositories and that also didn't work. Can you offer advice for that as well?

Comment: I have had some difficulty with opening Peek on 17.10, though it may be unrelated. If you have Peek installed, can you try to run `peek` in a terminal? If so, does it give any output?

Comment: Not sure how to include screenshots but heres the output
`
You need to connect this snap to the gnome platform snap.

You can do this with those commands:
snap install gnome-3-26-1604
snap connect peek:gnome-3-26-1604 gnome-3-26-1604

(the '3-26-1604' number defines the platform version and might change)
`

Comment: @fakedad Peek works when I switched over to xorg

Comment: If you don't want to stick with X.org, evidently [Green Recorder](https://github.com/foss-project/green-recorder) allows recording in Wayland. When you switch to X.org, does Typora work? If not, are you able to at least record your screen with Peek so you can get help from the developers?

Answer (score 2):

Your icons for launching applications might resume working after you logout and login again. If that doesn't work, try updating the software with the Software Updater or from the terminal using the following commands:

```
sudo apt update  
sudo apt upgrade
```

It doesn't look like Typora markdown editor has any functionality that [Mark Text](https://marktext.app/) markdown editor hasn't got. Mark Text is distributed in Linux as an appimage. Mark Text is better than Typora at accurately capturing everything on a webpage and Typora has a more user-friendly editor, so I use both applications. I use Mark Text as a webpage grabber, and then I copy/paste the markdown text I captured into Typora and use Typora to edit it.

Comment: I appreciate your help. Although I will try your suggestion, i'm not looking for a workaround. I should be able to install and run the applications I __want__. Surely there is an actual fix for this?